# C++/C#/Java video analysis question

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, video-processing

Could someone give references / frameworks, which allow to do something like `Microsoft Kinect` does, but using only one video stream?

I would like to see algorithm abstracts and papers if there are some *(I hope there are)*.

*If somebody had practical experience of using them, please share it :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/hands_gesture_recognition.aspx) project, it implements simple recognition algorithm of the hands gesture using one video stream.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is  [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/index.html). I love this library. A simple google search will yield plenty of info.